# Jquery mobile accordion shows "plus"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I was trying to use a Jquery Mobile 1.1.0 collapsible div and then an accordion on a non-mobile site, that is a site which will be responsive.

I've used them before on fully-mobile sites, and had no issues, but this time the word "plus" appears above the plus, breaking the layout:
[image: screenshot]

I have included all the JS and CSS files.  My code is the basic stuff from the docs page:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>I'm a header</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is impossible to debug without a JSFiddle.

Comment: I agree with @EvanMulawski maybe this will help? http://jsfiddle.net/EN6nD/ or an update to your question with a link to your code? A better example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code looks fine, here is also the options you might have

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-options.html

JSFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/EN6nD/

HTML:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
   <h3>I'm a header</h3>
   <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
</div>​
```

Comment: Thanks.  All I can think is that there is CSS somewhere else overriding it.